# How to populate a JavaScript array with a SilverStripe loop

Tags: javascript, silverstripe

I have a .SS file with a JavaScript array inside a script tag which needs to be populated with data from the backend.

The data is different dates and the JavaScript array needs to look something like this after it has been populated:

```
var dateArray = ['01/02/2014', '01/03/2016', '05/02/2014'];
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
<script>
  var dateArray = <% loop $Children %>[$ID],<% end_loop %>;
  var contentArray = <% loop $Children %>[$IDcontent],<% end_loop %>;
</script>
```

I have also tried this:

```
<% if $Children %>
<% loop $Children %>
    <script>
    var dateArray = [$ID];
    var contentArray = [$IDcontent];
    </script>
<% end_loop %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
var dateArray = [<% loop $Children %>"$ID"<% if not $Last %>,<% end_if %><% end_loop %>];
```

Comment: There are no console errors and the array gets created but no data gets added to the array

Comment: I edited the answer, try with $Children. i took $ID from your example, not sure if this is really dates.

Comment: Again the same happens the object gets created but no errors. I know this because I'm logging the object to the console. I've also tried to use interpolation (Template literals) like so `  `${$ID}`  `

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to run a `loop` inside of a script tag. You can loop the script tag or pull in data from an HTML element. For this type of issue, you would need to pull in the data from an HTML element like shown below.

For example:

**HTML**

```
<p class="GrabDate">
    <% loop $Children %>$ID <% if not $Last %>,<% end_if %><% end_loop %>
</p>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var dateArray = parseInt($(".GrabDate").text());
```

This would allow your function to run like intended without issues. You would need to hide the `.GrabDate` class.

Comment: Actually, it is possible to use a SilverStripe loop inside of a `<script>` tag in a .ss template. Having said that, this is valid alternate solution.

Comment: Instead of putting the data as content and then hiding the element, I think this could be improved by putting the data into a data attribute on the tag. For example `<div class="calendar" data-script-dates="SilverStripe loop goes here">...</div>`. Those values can then be fetched with `jQuery('.calendar').data('script-dates');`

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using an object and this seems to work:

```
<script>
var myEvents = [
      <% loop Children %>
      {
        date: $ID,
        content: '$ID'
      },
      <% end_loop %>
    ];
<script/>
```

I realise this doesn't exactly answer the OP but you can covert an object into a string.